# How to catch event that visibility of Xamarin.Forms View has changed

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Consider a ScrollView that has child Views that are expensive to render. In that scenario you want to handle visibility events so that only when a child view becomes visible you start rendering it and when the view becomes invisible you cancel any ongoing rendering and release resources that are required to maintain its view and interaction with it.

I have Googled and searched here on SO but to no avail. I have also gone through the API documentation of Xamarin. Especially the [documentation of the `View` class](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.View/).

Event handlers come in two flavors: explicit event members and overridable methods that are typically called `OnSomeKindOfEvent`.

Class `View` has no candidates for the intended purpose. If I go up the class hierarchy (both base classes and interfaces) I find VisualElement and then Element. Both classes have no suitable events or overridables.

I have also taken a look at `ScrollView` itself. It has a single event called `Scrolled`. [The link to ScrolledEventArgs](https://developer.xamarin.com/404?link=%2Fapi%2Ftype%2FSystem.EventHandler%3CXamarin.Forms.ScrolledEventArgs%3E%2F) in the API documentation takes me to a 404. If I google for "xamarin forms ScrolledEventArgs" I find [the page to which the API should have linked](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.ScrolledEventArgs/).The EventArgs class has two properties: ScrollX and ScrollY. This is not helpful either.

Anyone?

Comment: I do not believe there is a built-in API for this. You might be able to sub-class your own `View` and add the respective Event Handlers based on Visibility properties.

Comment: Could you convert the ScrollView / Views to ListView / DataTemplate to take advantage of ListView's ItemAppearing and ItemDisappearing?

Comment: Those are worth a try. Thanks!

Comment: Why is `ScrollX` and `ScrollY` not helpful? It seems to me that you could combine that information with the width/height of the `ScrollView` to figure out the currently visible viewport, and then figure out which child visuals should be visible, and go from there?

Comment: @KeithRome ScrollX and ScrollY are indeed helpful as you describe.